# Using Crontab with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, cron, redhat

I'm trying to schedule a python script to run every minute or every hour.

What I did so far :

crontab -e

In the crontab file I added

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /path/to/script/script.py
```

After I save the file I get the message

crontab: installing new crontab

However crontab is not running the script.

Any ideas?

Thanks, 
Diez

Comment: Perhaps the script is blowing up. Try `* * * * * /usr/bin/python /path/to/script/script.py >>/tmp/script.out 2>&1`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I will put here the solution maybe it helps someone. 
I tried putting in crontab -e * * * * * /usr/bin/python /path/to/script/script.py >>/tmp/script.out 2>&1 as Rafal suggested however the output was blank.

I read a lot about crontab last night and I found out that if you use a script with crontab and you write your output in a certain file you will need to modify your script and input the exact path for the file. If you don't put the full path the script will work when you run it manually. The script will still work if you run it with crontab but it won't know where to place its output.

So modifying

```
with open('output.txt', 'a') as f
```

with

```
with open('/path/to/file/output.txt', 'a') as f
```

did the job for me.

Thanks, 
Diez

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the script (e.g. scripts which prints a message to the console) you won't be able to distinguish whether the script is running or not.

You can assure that crontab is running correctly by typing in the console:

`tail -f /var/log/syslog`